# Pygame: image not appearing on moving background

Tags: python, background, pygame

my code was working fine when i didnt have a moving background. But now, i started making my character move from left to right and it stopped showing up. Ive been trying to figure out what the issue is for days, please help!! Thanks!!!

the following is the line of code i used for the background and character:

```
# create class for character (object)
class player(object):
    def __init__(self, x, y, width, height):  # initialize attributes
        self.x = x
        self.y = y
        self.width = width
        self.height = height
        self.left = True
        self.right = True
        self.isJump = False
        self.stepCount = 0
        self.jumpCount = 10
        self.standing = True

    def draw(self, screen):
        if self.stepCount + 1 >= 27:  # 9 sprites, with 3 frames - above 27 goes out of range
            self.stepCount = 0

        if not self.standing:
            if self.left:
                screen.blit(leftDirection[self.stepCount // 5], (self.x, self.y), )
                self.stepCount += 1
            elif self.right:
                screen.blit(rightDirection[self.stepCount // 5], (self.x, self.y), )
                self.stepCount += 1
        else:
            if self.right:
                screen.blit(rightDirection[0], (self.x, self.y))  # using index, include right faced photo
            else:
                screen.blit(leftDirection[0], (self.x, self.y))


class enlargement(object):
    def __init__(self, x, y, radius, color, facing):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y
        self.radius = radius
        self.color = color
        self.facing = facing

    def draw(self, screen):
        pygame.draw.circle(screen, self.color, (self.x, self.y), self.radius, 1)



#  main loop

speed = 30  # NEW
man = player(200, 410, 64, 64)  # set main character attributes
run = True
while run:
    redrawGameWindow()  # call procedure
    clock.tick(speed)  # NEW
    backgroundX -= 1.4  # Move both background images back
    backgroundX2 -= 1.4

    if backgroundX < background.get_width() * -1:  # If our background is at the -width then reset its position
        backgroundX = background.get_width()

    if backgroundX2 < background.get_width() * -1:
        backgroundX2 = background.get_width()

    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            run = False
            pygame.quit()
            quit()

    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            run = False
    keys = pygame.key.get_pressed()
    if keys[pygame.K_LEFT]:
        man.left = True
        man.right = False
        man.standing = False  # false, because man is walking
    # verify that character is within window parameters
    elif keys[pygame.K_RIGHT]:
        man.right = True
        man.left = False
        man.standing = False  # false, because man is walking
    else:
        man.standing = True
        man.stepCount = 0

    if not man.isJump:
        if keys[pygame.K_SPACE]:
            man.isJump = True  # when jumping, man shouldn't move directly left or right
            man.right = False
            man.left = False
            man.stepCount = 0
    else:
        if man.jumpCount >= -10:
            neg = 1
            if man.jumpCount < 0:
                neg = -1
            man.y -= (man.jumpCount ** 2) * 0.5 * neg  # to jump use parabola
            man.jumpCount -= 1
        else:
            man.isJump = False
            man.jumpCount = 10
```

Comment: where do you draw background? Where is `redrawGameWindow()` ? Do you draw player after drawing background and before screen `flip()`/`update()` ?

Comment: I TOTALLY forgot to add this protion of code (with the background) - thanks!   
     def redrawGameWindow():
    screen.blit(background, (0, 0))
    man.draw(screen)
    # background images for right to left moving screen
    screen.blit(background, (backgroundX, 0))
    screen.blit(background, (backgroundX2, 0))
    pygame.display.update()

Comment: always put code, data and error message in question, not in comment. It will be more readable and more people will see it.

Comment: code `redrawGame` shows that you draw player before you draw backgroud so you remove player from screeen. You have to always draw background before all other elements. And you don't need to draw background in `(0,0)` because moving background will also remove it.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion and help - I really appreciate it!!! However, I am a bit confused if i should change the location of the "redrawGame" function. If i should move it, where? Also, when I removed the ("0") from it, it said "error in destination". THANKS!!!!!

Comment: see my answer - you don't have to move `redrawGame` but lines inside this function. And you have to remove full line which have `(0,0)`

Answer (score 0):

Background removes all from screen - so you have to always draw background before any other elements.

You don't need to draw static background in `(0,0)` because moving background also remove it.

```
def redrawGameWindow():
    # background
    screen.blit(background, (backgroundX, 0))
    screen.blit(background, (backgroundX2, 0))

    man.draw(screen)

    pygame.display.update()
```